# Which level designer created the map Q2DM1 on Quake 2?

Tags: quake-2

Just curious to know which level designer created the map Q2DM1 on Quake 2.

Comment: There is a q2dm1 remake, made recently for The old BUILD game Shadow Warrior.
http://swcentral.weebly.com/the-edge.html - just thought I'd throw that in there :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it was Tim Willits... I remember seeing an interview with him where he was credited for creating "*possible the greatest map ever*", "*The Edge*". I tried finding it- a quick Google search only returned various references to him being the creator.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Willits
http://lvlworld.com/review.php?id=1286

At any rate, I'm quite certain he is the original creator. He even did a remake or two for other id tech based games.